# Prolog, find a item in given list of sublists and return sublist containing item(the one we are searching) and store it in a new list

Tags: list, prolog

%ProLog, Find will take three inputs which is

```
[item], [[a,0,0,1], [b,0,0,0]], StoreItHere
```

Code:

```
find([H|T], [[H|T1]|T2], ShiftData):-                
   append([], T1, ShiftData).
```

Output:

```
find([a],[[a,1,0,0], [b,0,0,0]], StoreItHere).           
StoreItHere = [1,0,0].
```

%% Now, I want to iterate through a item's list to search for subsist in a list of subsists.

For eg. if the input is:

```
find([a,b,c,d],
     [[a,1,0,0],[b,0,0,0],[z,1,0,0],[h,0,1,0],[c,1,0,0],[d,1,1,0],
      StoreItHere).
```

Output Should be:

```
StoreItHere = [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,0]].
```

Code that I write gives me False.

Code:-

```
find([H|T], [[H|T1]|T2], ShiftData):-                
   append([], T1, ShiftData),
   find(T), T2, ShiftData).
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I apologize, I am using this website for first time. I don't want anyone to write the code for me. I just want to know what should I do and how should I proceed, imagine working in a group and you are stuck and looking for ideas/help. I tried many things and everything fails and I don't think its appropriate to add everything that I try. Again. I am sorry.

Comment: You realize `append([], T1, ShiftData),` is the same thing as `T1 = ShiftData` right, since this means `ShiftData` is the result of appending `[]` (the empty list) to `T1`. This is a syntax error: `find(T), T2, ShiftData).`